# EmberJS: Link to next Record

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am building a simple image gallery. Currently i am stucked with the nextImage method.
What i expected is a list of model-ids. So i just increment the id in #nextImage.

- #/photos/1
- #/photos/2
- #/photos/3

But emberjs uses 'random' ids as the URL

- photos/ember283
- photos/ember352

**Question: How to i link from one image to the next image**

---

**This is how I create the records in one of the controllers**

```
//...
record = App.Photo.createRecord
      src : dataUrl
      title : "sometitle"

record.store.commit();
```

**photo_controller**

```
App.PhotoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  nextImage : ->
    length = App.Photo.find().get('length')
    id = parseInt(@get "content.id")
    nextId = if id == length then 1 else id+1

    @transitionToRoute 'photo', App.Photo.find(nextId)
```

**Template to list photos**

```
{{#each photo in controller}}
    <div style="margin: 5px">
        {{#linkTo photos.photo photo}}
        <img width="100" heigth="100"
        {{bindAttr src="photo.url"
        alt="photo.title"
        title="photo.title"}} />
        {{/linkTo}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

**Template for one photo**

```
   <a href="#" {{action nextImage}}>
    <img {{bindAttr src="url"}} />
        {{title}}
   </a>
```

**App_router**

```
App.Router.map ->
  @route "start"
  @route "photos"
  @route "photo",
    path: "/photos/:photo_id"
```

**Store**

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend
  revision: 12,
  adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have assumptions about the ids being created. What about this alternative implementation of nextImage?

```
App.PhotoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs : ["photos"], //will be accessible via 'controllers.photos'
    nextImage : function(photo){
        var pc = this.get("controllers.photos"); //get the photos controller
        var indexOf = pc.indexOf(photo);
        var next = null;
        if(indexOf + 1 === pc.get("length"))
            next = pc.objectAt(indexOf +1);
        else
            next = pc.objectAt(0);
        this.get("target").send("photo", next);

    }
});
```

**How does it work?**
Via the needs property, you get access to the photos controller. Now i am using the photocontroller to determine the next photo to show. This has the additional advantage that you do not have to issue an additional request if you use a REST-Adapter.